# Form causing VB process to not end when program execution finishes

Tags: vb.net, forms, process

I have a small VB project that seemingly works fine, unless I show any form in a certain function.

In the code below, `form_progress` is shown, (and then hidden later in the function), but the process does not end when execution does (all forms are closed), and consquently I'm stuck in debug unless I manually end it. Please note that if I comment out `form_progress.Show()`, the process ends as expected once all forms are closed.

At first I focused on the problem being with the `form_progress` form, but it is not - any form I show at this point causes this problem. No error is being thrown, so I'm lost as to where to look. If anyone has any suggestions I'd appriciate it. Thanks.

```
Public Sub complete_action(folder As String, rename As Boolean, include_sub_folders As Boolean)

    Dim dir As DirectoryInfo            ' The directory that they user selected as an object
    Dim output As String                ' The output to be placed in the log

    ' Set 'output' to be an empty string (to avoid errors)
    output = ""

    Try

        form_progress.Show()

        ' Set the DirectoryInfo object from the users selected directory name
        dir = New DirectoryInfo(folder)

        If include_sub_folders Then
            output = recursive_loop(dir, rename, output)
        Else
            output = loop_folder(dir, folder, rename)
        End If

        ' Write the log file
        write_text.Log_File.write_to_file(output)

        form_progress.Hide()

    Catch oError As Exception
        functions.error_handler(oError, "Error when looping through files", "complete_action")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using form_progress.Close() instead of Hide().

Comment: Of course, thank you. I was completly blind to that because I was focusing on the fact the form was being shown as the cause of the problem!!